# encoding error accessing postgresql from wildfly

Tags: postgresql, encoding, wildfly

just setting up new computer and I can't get my wildfly to connect to the postgres. I'm using same standalone.xml as on old computer.
The postgres database is configured to UTF8 (default). Usign pgadmin, I restored from backup and it shows german Umlaute correctly.
But when I start wildfly, I get following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Ung³ltige UTF-8-Sequenz: das erste Byte ist 10xxxxxx: 187
        at org.postgresql.core.UTF8Encoding.decode(UTF8Encoding.java:104)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveString(PGStream.java:331)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:705)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
        ... 35 more
```

sorry for the german error message. I have no idea why this message is in german.

any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Try to start wildfly by forcing some JVM system properties in the command line, eg the user locale (-Duser.locale=en-US) and/or the file encoding (-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8)

Comment: Check your db configuration once. And German might be coming from the Locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out that there is an issue with parsing error messages coming with a different locale. Apparently the postgresql jdbc driver can only handle english error messages and there was an error.

Root cause: I made a spelling mistake for a table in the database. That caused Postgresql to throw an error. But it threw the error with a german error message. And the postgresql jdbc driver was unable to parse it and threw a new error as shown in the question.

I fixed the original spelling error and with the root cause gone, there was no more error message to parse.

a year later (now) I finally fixed the locale issue by editing the standalone.xml:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/PostgresDS" ...>
    ...
    <new-connection-sql>SET lc_messages TO 'en_US.UTF-8'</new-connection-sql>
    ...
</datasource>
```